# Couldn't find any package by regex 'ant1.7'

Tags: software-installation

I want to install ant1.7 in Linux but I cannot, the error message is given below:

```
Couldn't find any package by regex 'ant1.7'
```

can you help me ?

Comment: Try just `ant`.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu different versions of `ant` package corresponds to different versions of the Linux kernel. Look [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ant).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

you can also to fix existing before or instead:

```
sudo apt-get install -f ant
```

or:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ant
```

Comment: "different versions of the Linux kernel"? What? O.o What does the kernel have to do with `ant`? Did you mean different Ubuntu releases?

Comment: hahaha. thank you @muru, now I know how to crack myself )) let it to be an imaginative or figurative expression ... suggest your pronounce, if your views about Ubuntu versions densely closer to the most common or some less definitive trope.

Comment: I am ashamed that was lazy to build the phrase.